# Add images to jar library

Tags: android, image, addition

I want to add images to a jar-library to prevent that anyone can change it, but i don't know how to do it.
Could somebody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking for some other ways, i test the "base 64 code/decode" and it works really good. Only need do this:

```
String encodedImage = "encoded string of image";    
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Then only need to setImageBitmap to the ImageView or like you need.

To encode the image i used this:

http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Comment: Which encoding did you use?

Answer (score 1):

1)Right click on your project -> Export.

2)Expand java folder and select "Jar File"

3)Click Next. ( a window will open up).

4)Select the classes and the image file you want to export as jar. 
( in "select the resources to export" panel )

5) set the export destination and click finish.

Now the jar will have all the classes and the image file you want.

Comment: This is assuming you're using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Any means of putting an image on a device will allow sufficiently motivated users the ability to change it. Whatever you think "add images to a jar-library" means will not change that.

If you do not want users changing your images, do not put the image on the user's device.

Comment: To build on this point, a JAR file is just a renamed ZIP file. So anyone who gets access to your JAR has access to that file, they just need to rename to .ZIP and get the image.